# Number of conjugacy classes of integral matrices with irreducible characteristic polynomials and ideal classes

Tags: matrices, reference-request, soft-question

Let $f\in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ be an **irreducible monic** polynomial of degree $n$.

A well-known theorem of Latimer and McDuffee states that their is a bijection between the following sets:

- the set of $\mathbb{Z}$-similarity  classes of matrices $A\in M_n(\mathbb{Z})$ with characteristic polynomial $f$
- the set of ideal classes of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, where $\alpha$ is a fixed complex root of $f$.

To precise the terminology:

- Two matrices $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{Z})$ are $\mathbb{Z}$-similar if there exists $P\in GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ such that  $A=PBP^{-1}$.
- Two non zero ideals $I,J$ of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ are equivalent if there exists $x\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)^\times$ such that $I=xJ$.
  An ideal class is an equivalence class for this relation. Note that the quotient set is not a group since we consider also non invertible ideals.

Now, in all the references I found, it is claimed (see for example [the wikipedia page on Latimer-McDuffee theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latimer%E2%80%93MacDuffee_theorem)) that
"since an order in a number field has only finitely many ideal classes (even if it is not the maximal order, and we mean here ideals classes for all nonzero ideals, not just the invertible ones), it follows that there are only finitely many conjugacy classes of matrices wirh characteristic polynomial $f$."

My main problem is that, despite all my efforts, I am not able to find a reference for this claim.
All the references talks about the group of invertible ideals. SO my first question is:

**Question 1.** Do you know a reference where it is explicitely proved that, given an order $\mathcal{O}$ of a ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ of a number field $K$, the number of ideals classes of $\mathcal{O}$ is finite. Even the particular case $\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ will make me happy.

I happily assume that finiteness is known for $\mathcal{O}_K$.

Note that I know more or less how to do it. If $m$ is the index of $\mathcal{O}$, then any prime ideal coprime to $m$ is invertible. Now the class group of invertible ideals is finite (but this is not trivial at all). And I think (???) that the number of prime ideals which are not coprime to $m$ is finite. But a clear reference would be better for my purpose.

Also, I cannot imagine that a proof of the finiteness of the number of $\mathbb{Z}$-similarity classes has to use number theory, so :

**Question 2.** Do you know an ad hoc proof or a reference containing an ad hoc proof of the finiteness of the number of $\mathbb{Z}$-similarity classes ?

Comment: So I take it that, in particular, there is not a reference in the paper linked on that wikipedia page?

Comment: I agree that the references of this paper (which are located in its footnotes) could give at least part of the answer. I also wanted to express my amazement that such a theorem was “well-known”! Finally, I’m not completely sure, however, that you can reduce the finiteness problem to prime ideals: the order is not a Dedekind ring, so there’s no reason why an general ideal class should be generated by primes… maybe the “geometry of numbers” approach still works?

Comment: By the way, the case $n=2$ and $f(0)=1$ (i.e. $A \in \text{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$) is discussed in [my answer here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/236151/conjugacy-classes-of-mathrmsl-2-mathbbz/236162#236162), although the class number connection is only discussed in the final paragraph and the comments. You'll find some references for that case in the other answers.